# Can I use EnvDTE and VisualStudio.SDK in a .Net 6 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, envdte

With VisualStudio 2019, I used to be able to use EnvDTE80 that comes with VS2019 installation. It worked fine within my .Net 3.1 project. Then I upgraded my project to .Net 6 using VS2022. It appears that Microsoft introduced some breaking changes. For one, EnvtDTE is now part of VisualStudio SDK that can be downloaded as a Nuget or installed using VS installer. However, after installing it in both ways, I'm unable to access Microsoft.VisualStudio namespace as well as EnvDTE. I spent a couple of days trying to look up more information, but couldn't find anything useful. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

P.S the project is a 64-bit WPF desktop application using .Net 6.

For more context, I'm trying to open an instance of Visual Studio, load a C++ project, add files to it and build/run the project using EnvDTE:

```cs
    static class VisualStudio
    {
            private static EnvDTE80.DTE2 _vsInstance = null;
            private static readonly string _progID = "VisualStudio.DTE.17.0";
            
            [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
            private static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

            [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
            private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(uint reserved, out IRunningObjectTable pprot);

            public static void OpenVisualStudio(string solutionPath)
            {
                IRunningObjectTable rot = null;
                IEnumMoniker monikersTable = null;
                IBindCtx bindCtx = null;
                try
                {
                    if (_vsInstance == null)
                    {
                        int hResult = GetRunningObjectTable(0, out rot);
                        if (hResult < 0 || rot == null) throw new COMException($"GetRunningObjectTable() returned HRESULT: {hResult:X8}");

                        rot.EnumRunning(out monikersTable);
                        monikersTable.Reset();

                        hResult = CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);
                        if (hResult < 0) throw new COMException($"CreateBindCtx() returned HRESULT: {hResult:X8}");

                        IMoniker[] currentMoniker = new IMoniker[1];
                        
                        while (monikersTable.Next(1, currentMoniker, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
                        {
                            string name = "";

                            currentMoniker[0]?.GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out name);
                            if (name.Contains(_progID))
                            {
                                hResult = rot.GetObject(currentMoniker[0], out object obj);
                                if (hResult < 0) throw new COMException($"Running Object Table GetObject() returned HRESULT: {hResult:X8}");
                                EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = obj as EnvDTE80.DTE2;

                                var solutionName = string.Empty;                                                        
                                solutionName = dte.Solution.FullName;                            

                                if (solutionName == solutionPath)
                                {
                                    _vsInstance = dte;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (_vsInstance == null)
                        {
                            Type visualStudioType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(_progID, true);
                            _vsInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(visualStudioType) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());                
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (monikersTable != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(monikersTable);
                    }

                    if (rot != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rot);
                    }

                    if (bindCtx != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bindCtx);
                    }
                }
            }

        public static void BuildSolution(string solutionPath)
        {

            OpenVisualStudio(solutionPath);

            if (!_vsInstance.Solution.IsOpen)
                _vsInstance.Solution.Open(solutionPath);

            _vsInstance.MainWindow.Visible = true;

            var configName = "Debug"; // Or Release 
            _vsInstance.Solution.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Item(configName).Activate();
            _vsInstance.ExecuteCommand("Build.BuildSolution");
        }
}
```

Comment: What you are exactly trying to do is unclear. Do you have a small reproducing project? Code?

Comment: @SimonMourier I updated my question. I stripped some synchronization stuff out to make the snippet shorter (e.g. wait for visual studio to actually finish loading, before doing anything else, `MessageFilter` etc.) . Most of the time it goes into a kind of infinite wait  state when I try to open the solution at the line that say `_vsInstance.Solution.Open(solutionPath);`.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me, it opens and build a solution fine.

Comment: ok, thanks for giving it a try. For me it fails occasionally on two different machines. Maybe there's some other part of the code that causes the problem.